# How to make constraint different for id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

In my ReactJS app I'm fetching information from my NodeJS app to display on the page the album by id. When I add songs to my database it has to go through the POST request and add the info to the database but the database has a constraint where the index key has to be unique. What I'm trying to do in the code below is use Promises to select album by id then insert the data on that album_id so that the insert and constraint is only ran on that id. This doesn't work and the constraint is still ran on all objects the same. Does anyone have a solution as on what I could do in order to run the constraint separately so that different albums can have the same index?

```
  const addSong = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
   const { name, link, index, album_id } = request.body;

  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(true) {
      resolve('Success')
    } else {
      reject('Failed')
    }
  })

  for (let i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
    const object = request.body[i]
    p.then(() => {
       pool.query('SELECT * FROM songs WHERE album_id = $1', [album_id], (error, results) => {
       if (error) {
        throw error
      } else {
       console.log("SELECT " + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    }
    })
    })

      .then(() => {
        pool.query(
          'INSERT INTO songs (name, link, index, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *',
          [
            object.name,
            object.link,
            object.index,
            object.album_id,
          ],
          (error, results) => {
            if (error != null) {
              console.log(error)
            } else {
              console.log('INSERT ' + JSON.stringify(request.body))
            }
          }
        )
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "index key has to be unique"? I mean... unique is unique. Maybe that's not actually what you want, you probably *actually* want uniqueness based on the album_id/index *combination*.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I think I would want something like the index has to be different only if the album_id is the same. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Don't mix promises with callback-style code. `pool.query` perfectly returns promises already, don't pass a callback! That allows you to do proper chaining.

Comment: @DDavis25 To do that, change the table constraints. Please show us the Postgres (DDL) code where you defined the table.

Comment: @Bergi How to I get the code?

Comment: @DDavis25 Who set up the database? Ask them.

Comment: @Bergi 
CREATE TABLE public.songs (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(200),
    link character varying(30),
    index integer,
    album_id integer
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.songs
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_index UNIQUE (index);

Comment: @DDavis25 There you are, the `UNIQUE` constraint is only for the `index` column, while it should cover also the `album_id` column. Change to something like `CONSTRAINT unique_index_per_album UNIQUE (album_id, index)`. (Btw, the `id` column looks like it should become a `PRIMARY KEY`, no?)

Comment: Btw, your nodejs code doesn't make a lot of sense. What's the `SELECT * FROM song` good for, you never do anything with its `results`? And you seem to be unclear whether the parsed `request.body` is an object or an array, as you use it in both roles.

Comment: @Bergi your code works for me. Thanks. The `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`. I believe the `request.body` was an array. What should have I done with the `results` in that situation?

Comment: If it's an array, you should remove the line `const { name, link, index, album_id } = request.body;`. And regarding the `SELECT`, I'd drop the entire query if you don't need any results from it.